# dump out SQL tables to CSV

Tags: java, csv

I am using openCSV 3.6 library in Java NetBeans to dump data from SQL query ResultSet to csv file with following command

```
  FileWriter my_csv=new FileWriter("out.csv");
  CSVWriter my_csv_output = new CSVWriter(my_csv);  
  boolean includecolumnnames=false;
  my_csv_output.writeAll(rs,includecolumnnames); 
  my_csv_output.close();
```

in my output I am only getting column name but not any data.

Could you please help how to get data with column name

Comment: Maybe your ResultSet doesn't have any data?

Comment: Is there data? Sure the resultset isn't empty?

Comment: Yes there is data  and I have used                                                         *********resultTable.setModel (DbUtils.resultSetToTableModel(rs)) *************                             to show data in table format and its shows all the data